# crash if sdk mapquest and volley

Tags: android, android-volley, mapquest

I use mapquest sdk with a simple map and marker
The app crashes when I just add the Volley library to gradle

```
9228-9228/com.example.aklox.aklox A/libc: 
/usr/local/google/buildbot/src/android/ndk-r15-release/external/libcxx/../../external/libcxxabi/src/abort_message.cpp:74: void abort_message(const char *, ...): assertion "terminating with uncaught exception of type jni::PendingJavaException" failed
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT), code -6 in tid 9228 (ple.aklox.aklox)
```

graddle as following :

```
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.0'
implementation 'com.mapquest:mapping-android-sdk:2.0.5'    // for Mapping SDK MapView
```

before adding the implementation line for volley, it worked fine !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Insert the following into your project's `build.gradle` file:**

```
allprojects {
  repositories {
       // mq maven repo
      maven { url 'http://artifactory.cloud.mapquest.com/artifactory/et-android-binaries' }
  }
}
```

**Then, insert the following into your application's `build.gradle` file:**

```
implementation('com.mapquest:mapping-android-sdk:2.0.5')   // for Mapping SDK MapView
```